# How is this body fadeIn animation done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I discovered the "http://thegoodman.cc/". It's an absolutely amazing website.

I am just really really curious, as to how the body of this document is slightly faded in, and slide up in this page:

> http://thegoodman.cc/about/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's done using CSS animations. When looking at [the source](http://thegoodman.cc/files/main.css), you'll find this line of code:

```
.sup {
    animation:sup 1.8s backwards;
}
@keyframes sup {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
        transform:translateY(50px);
    }
    30% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
        transform:translateY(0);
    }
}
```

It'll fade in the text (using `opacity`) and move it up using `translateY` .

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UNkjF/).

Take note it's using the [Prefix Free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) JS library to prevent having to add prefixes like `-webkit-`, `-moz-` etc.

Comment: No problem - glad to help you out. Don't forget to accept this answer if it satisfied your needs.